# how to npm install only devDependencies with node 8.7.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

The usual way of installing only devDependencies was to use `npm install --only=dev` (or `--only=production` if you want only dependencies).

This doesn't work anymore in 8.7. If I run this command, npm will try installing *all* dependencies. Or at least, it runs a `/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t` on packages that are not in `devDependencies`. Those packages being in private git repos, the npm install fails for me.

This didn't happen until I upgraded to 8.7.0, from 7.4.0

The [npm cli documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) still shows the old way of doing it though.

Is there a new syntax for that option?

Comment: My bad on the stupid answer. I read through too quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output of `npm help install`:

> npm install **(in package directory, no arguments)**:
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
>
> In global mode (ie, with `-g` or `--global` appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.
>
> By default, `npm install` will install all modules listed as dependencies in npm help 5 `package.json`.
>
> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`), npm will not install modules listed in            `devDependencies`.

So it seems you can install only `dependencies` with `--production`; not sure if there's a way to only install `devDependencies`.